# Alice Bob Coin Optimal Solution

Tags: c, algorithm

Consider this question I found on hackerrank:
[Coins Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/minixtreme/challenges/coins)

> > Alice and Bob were sitting in the sun; drinking orange juice; and watching some migrating ducks fly to Africa. “Look”, noted Alice, “one
> >     of the ducks left a trail of golden coins on the floor”. “Great!”
> >     exclaimed Bob, “let‟s play a game with this line of coins. We will
> >     take turns, where each one of us will flip one coin from „head‟ into
> >     „tail‟ state”. “Ok”, agreed Alice and added, “but when we flip a coin,
> >     we can also opt to flip the coin immediately after it, even if that
> >     coin is a „tail‟, in which case it becomes a „head‟”. “And whoever can
> >     not play - loses” cried both of them simultaneously. Cunning Bob knew
> >     that he could count on witty IEEEXtreme contestants to help him win.
> >     Can you help him do that? Task Your task is to write a program that
> >     given a string of H/T letters, computes a winning move for the
> >     flip-coin game, if there is one, or reports that there in no winning
> >     move, if this is the case. A winning move is a legal move such that
> >     either the player wins immediately (because there are no more coins to
> >     flip), or else, after any subsequent move by the opponent there is a
> >     winning move for the player.
>
> For example, if the input is TTTT then Bob lost the game (there is no
>   “head” so he can not play and thus he lost). For the input TTTTHTTTT,
>   Bob wins by flipping the fifth coin; for the input TTHHT, Bob wins by
>   flipping both “Heads” (third and fourth coins); for the input
>   THHTHTHT, Bob wins if he flips coins 2 and 3.
>
> Input The input file to be read from the console contains one line in
>   which there is a string entirely composed of the letters H and T,
>   representing the state of the coins, as explained.
>
> Output    The output file, to be written at the console, contains one
>   line, with one number. A positive number N means that flipping the Nth
>   coin is a winning move. A negative number, written –N, means that
>   flipping the Nth and the N+1th coins is a winning move. Zero, written
>   0, means that there is no winning move. Note that, in general, there
>   can be several winning moves, for a given list of coins. Your program
>   can output any of them.

I tried a recursive backtracking solution however 'C' throws a Segmentation Fault error due to Stackoverflow. Here is my code:(It partially works)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()

    {

    char a[100];

    scanf("%s",a);

    printf("%d",check(a));



}

int check(char a[])

{

    //printf("%s\n",a);

    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){

        if(a[i]=='H'){

            a[i]='T';

            a[i+1]=a[i+1]=='H'?'T':'H';

            if(check(a)){

                a[i+1]=a[i+1]=='H'?'T':'H';

                if(check(a))a[i]='H';

                else return (i+1);

            }

            else return -(i+1);

        }

    }

    //printf("Lost\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: it must be an out-of-bounds array access. a debugger can help you.

Comment: If this kind of problem interests you then you should study the Game of Nim. Many games -- perhaps including this one -- are actually Nim in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly undoing all the moves that you attempt.  If you don't undo the moves, you can never backtrack.

Also, you are returning numbers from `check` which is being used as a boolean function.

Here is a sample that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//#define DEBUG(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FLIP(x) ( ((x)=='H') ? 'T' : 'H' )


bool check(char* a) {
  DEBUG("%s\n",a);

  // Loop over the string.
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++) {
    // If this coin is a head, try flipping it.
    if (a[i]=='H') {
      // Try flipping just this coin.
      a[i]=FLIP(a[i]);
      // See if it is a win or a loss for the other player.
      if (!check(a)) {
        // A loss for the other player means a win for us!
        // Undo our last move.
        a[i]=FLIP(a[i]);
        return true;
      }
      // A win for the other player.  
      // See if flipping the next coin makes a difference.
      if (i+1 < strlen(a)) {
        a[i+1]=FLIP(a[i+1]);
        // See if it is a win or a loss for the other player.
        if (!check(a)) {
          // A loss for the other player means a win for us!
          // Undo our last two moves.
          a[i]=FLIP(a[i]);
          a[i+1]=FLIP(a[i+1]);
          return true;
        }
        // Still a loss.  Undo this move.
        a[i+1]=FLIP(a[i+1]);
      }
      // Still a loss.  Undo this move.
      a[i]=FLIP(a[i]);
    } // if (a[i]=='H')
  } // for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++)

  // Loss.
  return false;
}

int main() {
  char a[100];
  scanf("%s",a);
  if (check(a)) {
    printf("Winner!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Loser!\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that there are too many input characters and they are overflowing your input array.

You could try changing the line:

```
char a[100];
```

to increase the 100 to a larger number.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is running into infinite loop when you enter character `H`.

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
    if(a[i]=='H'){  // if passes when input char `H`  
        a[i]='T';   // its changed to `T`
        a[i+1]=a[i+1]=='H'?'T':'H'; // Here a[1] becomes `H`
        if(check(a)) {  // goes back to function call and loops infinitely 
           ...
```

So you need to check your algorithm requirement to your code behaves.